# Trying to compile inherited Java project and gettting errors with Maven build for third party libraries

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java development, and I inherited a Java project. We are trying to recover some code from a decompiled JAR file.

I am trying to recompile it after making changes, and...

I am trying to compile it as such:

```
mvn clean compile process-classes
```

and I am getting the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project company-server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/search/attribute/ReflectionAttributeExtractor.java:[133,17] 'catch' without 'try'
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/search/attribute/ReflectionAttributeExtractor.java:[205,17] 'catch' without 'try'
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,87] illegal start of type
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,88] '(' or '[' expected
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,89] ';' expected
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,90] illegal start of type
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,105] ';' expected
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[40,145] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[43,45] ';' expected
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/source/hbm/TimestampAttributeSourceImpl.java:[51,6] illegal start of type
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/pathmap/UriTemplatePathSpec.java:[85,33] array dimension missing
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/pathmap/UriTemplatePathSpec.java:[85,34] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/io/WriteFlusher.java:[209,15] not a statement
[ERROR] /Users/name/Desktop/Projects/project-server-new/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/io/WriteFlusher.java:[209,20] ';' expected
```

Etc etc.

I go to the location in question for one of the errors (this particular one is in fasterxml/jackson):

```
if (!baseType.isCollectionLikeType()) ** GOTO lbl25
```

Is this an artifact of the decompile process?

Sorry if this is a basic question - I'm not too familiar with Java, JARs or decompile processes.

Comment: The decompiler you are using is not fully decompiling the class files you wish you use. You will have to find a better decompiler or fill in the blanks as you see them.

Comment: The problem only seems to be with third party libraries, so I'll redownload them.

Comment: As a followup to Joe's comment, You may want to look at the documentation for the decompiler you are using. Perhaps it has mode that will generate compilable code as opposed to 'annotated' code.